# WC Lovers - Multi Vendor Plug in - SQL query to link vendor names to an order

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build a custom report for WooCommerce Multi Vendor Plugin where I can link the vendor name to the order. I have no idea where to look.

I can pick up the orders in the wp_wcfm_marketplace_orders table, and I can see the VendorID, but I can't figure out the relationship between that table and the table that I think holds the vendor name

I'm looking at the "wp_usermeta2" table and the "meta_key" column which has two values that could possibly be used "store_name" or "wcfmmp_store_name"

Please help

Comment: You should probably use their API for querying data: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wcfm-marketplace-rest-api/

Comment: I'm running a BI tool that connects directly to our DB. The plug ins I've seen for reporting aren't meeting our needs

Comment: If it's Power BI it can send API calls.  Though, I'm not sure if it works for that plugin's API specifically.